# Quantum Kernel Method: If the input is the QK provided by the variable qiskit, is it still true?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, kernel-methods

The puzzle is from

Case 1: https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/03_quantum_kernel.html

Case 2: https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/08_quantum_kernel_trainer.html

Question 1: The above two cases indicate that although parameterized circuits are set, their parameters are all from the data set, so why does Case 2 have a training process?

Question 2: The datasets of case 1 and case 2 are ready, which means that the input of the kernel function is ready, but if the input of the quantum kernel function is uncertain, can the kernel function be dynamically learned? How to achieve it?

Question 3: The kernel function is the theoretical basis in the supervised learning field such as SVM. If the input is unlabeled data X and X1, that is, unsupervised learning, can the quantum kernel method continue to be used?

Comment: is it homework? I would suggest understand each step algorithm, and study the main step of what the questions is asking. for example, question 1: how does the plot data come from?(docs already label clearly how the data is extract out from `cb_qkt`)

Comment: focus, enjoy exploring it, you will learn a lot from answering those question.